# Игнорируется часть кликов

Tags: c#, счетчики, click

На днях понадобилось написать программу, которая считает количество кликов, совершенных человеком. Однако заметил, что отлавливается не каждый клик: если человек совершает хотя бы 2-3 щелчка в секунду, часть точно будет проигнорирована. Как с таким бороться? Отлавливаю с помощью элементарной

```
private void opg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Может просто частые клики воспринимаются как двойные?

Comment: Посмотрите на реакцию на двойные клики, скорее всего дело в этом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скорее всего, когда пользователь делает 2-3 клика в секунду, то это воспринимается системой как двойной клик (отдельное от обычного клика событие).

Попробуйте добавить:

```
private void opg_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count = count + 1;
}
```

Также разницу поясняет [справка от мелкомягких](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171543(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `count = count + 1;` или `++count;`, т.к. первый клик отработает по `opg_Click`

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик да, вы правы, спасибо - поправил.

Comment: или чтобы не писать код клика повторно можно `opg_Click(sender, e)` вписать в тело `opg_DoubleClick`, ну это на рассмотрение автора

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы очень мне помогли  :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно проще. Подпишитесь на событие MouseUp (или MouseDown).

Comment: Не любой MouseUp/MouseDown - клик.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно запретить обработку двойных кликов. Это можно сделать убрав соответствующий флаг из класса при создании формы:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private int clicks = 0;

  protected override CreateParams CreateParams
  {
    get
    {
      const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x8;
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
      cp.ClassStyle &= ~CS_DBLCLKS;
      return cp;
    }
  }

  private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Text = (++clicks).ToString();
  }
}
```